# add manifest to compiled exe file from jar

Tags: windows, jar, permissions, uac

I've a runnable MyApp.jar which I compiled to MyApp.exe by using launch4j and because this app need administrator permissions I try to add manifest file to it by following this article : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx
When I perform

```
mt.exe –manifest manifest.xml –outputresource:MyApp.exe;#1
```

the process completed without errors but MyApp.exe file reduces its size from 6mb to 32kb only and when I try to run it I got the following error: Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile.
Maybe somebody know what's wrong with it? 
My manifest file is attached below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0"> 
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0"
     processorArchitecture="X86"
     name="MyApp.exe"
     type="win32"/> 
  <description>{app name}</description> 
  <!-- Identify the application security requirements. -->
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel
          level="requireAdministrator"
          uiAccess="true"/>
        </requestedPrivileges>
       </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally we have solved this by adding manifest file through launch4j app during compilation time and changed  **uiAccess** flag from **true** to **false**  `uiAccess="false"` despite of the fact that our application is graphic, otherwise it didn't work.

I've used this file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0"> 
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0"
     processorArchitecture="X86"
     name="MyApp.exe"
     type="win32"/> 
  <description>{app name}</description> 
  <!-- Identify the application security requirements. -->
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel
          level="requireAdministrator"
          uiAccess="false"/>
        </requestedPrivileges>
       </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

And put it here:
[image]

Comment: Would it be possible to explain how you did this with Launch4j ? Many thanks !

Comment: @Tom, I'll be at work only at Sunday, will do few screenshots and update my answer.